# Beginner for App_code folder import

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, app-code

I am doing a C# tutorial, but got this error can't move on, I have set the Product class under the App_Code Folder, somehow is not loading or import it. any idea why?

> Server Error in '/Beginning ASP.NET 4' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Product' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
>
> Source File: c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Books\Beginning ASP.NET 4\Chapter03\Website\Default.aspx    Line: 8

Source Error:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product saleProduct = new Product("Kitchen Garbage", 49.99M, "garbage.jpg");
        Response.Write(saleProduct.GetHtml());
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Product Test</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you import the namespace? `using TheNameSpaceHere`

Comment: As Shyju mentioned, you're going to have to show us the error message, and possibly the part of the Product class instation and GetHTML method if the problem lies in there.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to copy paste the error message.

Comment: Try: <%@ import namespace="value"%>

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx

Just a tip --- you can have the C# in a separate file, rather than in the .aspx page.  Personally, this makes it a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Don't put code in markup. Put in [code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx) files!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Product saleProduct = new Product("Kitchen Garbage", "49.99M", "garbage.jpg");
```

put double quotes for 49.99M

Comment: If the class is expecting a decimal, than it's correct without the quotes. Having a string with the M wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
App_Code/Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Product(string _ProductName, string _Property2, string _Image)
    {
        this.ProductName = _ProductName;
        this.Property2 = _Property2;
        this.Image = _Image;
    }

    public string GetHtml
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table>");
            sb.Append(string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", this.ProductName, this.Property2, this.Image));
            sb.Append("<table>");
            return sb.ToString();

        }

    }


}
```

and this is the code from the Default.aspx.cs file.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Product saleProduct = new Product("Kitchen Garbage", "49.99M", "garbage.jpg");
    Response.Write(saleProduct.GetHtml);
}
```

Comment: Still got the same error: ... i must have done something wrong, the code just can't find the Product class
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Product' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the namespace of your Product class?  Any code that wants to use the Product class is going to have to either be, A) in the same namespace, or B) referencing the namespace.  So that if your Product class is in the Some.Random.Stuff namespace, your code that wants to call the Product class will need to write "using Some.Random.Stuff;" at the top.